# Can I get logged in user details in App service for a user who has logged in from Microsoft Dynamics?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-identity

I am trying to get the logged in user details on my application hosted in app service. The user has logged in via Microsoft Dynamics using Azure AD. My application (APIs) will be called from the Dynamics portal after the authentication for the user. I want to do the authorization for the logged in user before the user is able to access the APIs. Can someone help?

Comment: There is a built-in authentication for Azure App Service. Users can sign in without writing minimal or no code in your web app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Comment: First authentication is done by Dynamics I need to check the token validity and get user information.